# Confluent schema registry fails on start with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.confluent.rest.Application.parseListeners(Ljava/util/List;ILjava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.getPortForIdentity(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:204)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:133)
```

**etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties**

```
 listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081 
 kafkastore.connection.url=localhost:2181
 kafkastore.topic=_schemas
 debug=false
```

kafka and zookeeper are already running.

Why logs from zookeeper keep on coming like

```
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,352] INFO Accepted socket connection from /13.**.**.***:39572 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,352] WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,352] INFO Closed socket connection for client /13.58.108.150:39572 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,438] INFO Accepted socket connection from /13.**.**.***:39574 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,438] WARN Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.EOFException (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2017-10-17 09:57:31,438] INFO Closed socket connection for client /13.**.***.**:39574 (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

I was wondering maybe this will be the cause of failure for schema-registry.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchMethodError indicates your CLASSPATH is misconfigured.

It's not clear what version you're running or what OS you're using but Windows is not officially supported, and pater versions of Confluent Platform have likely fixed this, or using the Docker images should work as well

Answer (score 0):

in my situation the problem was caused by hostname, check if hostname is equal to "localhost"

### Problem "Scheme registry fail on start"

[image]

### Test Solution "set Hostname to "localhost""

[image]

#### If this solve your problem, you can config permantly yout hostname:

- modify file /etc/hostname